# how to log apps-script with user interaction?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I would like to log an apps-script that is meant to be run as a service, and requires user-interaction. The log journal (in google script editor) logs indeed the "doGet start" entry but not the "handler" one... as clicking on the "execute" button in the google editor does not show the UiApp.

The only way I found to effectively see the Ui is to publish the script and execute its public url... but then I don't know where to find the logs.

Any hint is welcome, thanks.

```
function doGet() {
  Logger.log("doGet start");
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle(" ");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('selectionHandler');
  var docsUI = app.createDocsListDialog().addSelectionHandler(handler).showDocsPicker();
  return app;
}

function selectionHandler(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log("handler");
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue - [Issue 811](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=811) which asks for a persistent logger function. Please star it to add your vote. In the absence of this feature, you can write the logs to a Spreadsheet cell or a document in your Google Drive which you can see . You can use the Logger.getLog() function to get the entire text of your logger thus far

Answer (score 5):

To debug my web deployed applications, I wrote a library which adds a log window to applications and permits to output messages to this window. The Library's Project Key is `MHDTOOt9dn-ViHNtwfsIfJ5lu8m0d5vP9`. There is a [demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbziFJ03JKDcMpKgBLpvzvFZZUFNYdMpbTfIX0qPkS7J6zF0OMON/exec) showing the abilities. The source code is also [available](https://script.google.com/d/1w8FDhOz4hyighGd7sLE64uS-yxEVRQwF_X0JXjDLTfH8uab9pba9DQ9D/edit).

I hope it can help you to workaround the Logger service problems.

Comment: dear number one, you are just brilliant and generous, this library is very clever and very useful ! thanks a lot :-) (I mean it !)

Comment: @Sergeinsas, thank you very much. Yes, It is quite handy. I use it every day. There is a coupe of ideas to extend it, for instance, an object logging - helpful to debug handlers parameters and log messages with format string like `printf` in `C`.

Comment: @Sergeinsas, BTW I've got a long awaited `Unsung Hero` badge. :)

Comment: Yes, I did notice that you know, he he... even if personal messages are not welcome on this forum it's always a pleasure to read your posts. thanks (from another unsung hero :-)

Comment: I think you should post your library on [the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502), a lot of people starred it and might be seduced ;-)

Comment: and your Unsung Hero badge is well deserved!

Comment: @Berteh. As I promised, I added new features to the library.

Comment: @Sergeinsas. As I promised, I added new features to the library.

Comment: Thanks, don't you have a site or a public Gdoc where you could explain how to use these features ? for example what argument should I use with start and stop PerformanceCounter ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas, I have an idea to create a blog, but still in progress. :-). I wrote code using the GAS documentation features. It is available by [this link](https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MHDTOOt9dn-ViHNtwfsIfJ5lu8m0d5vP9/6).

Comment: @Sergeinsas, just reviewed the documentation. It is not complete. I have to fix it. BTW, the demo is also updated to use the latest changes.

Comment: @megabyte1024 : beguining today there is an issue with your library, it doesn't work anymore and generates an error message 'atomic mutation is not yet allowed' (or something like that) Why do they change things on sunday ? I hate to have to work on sundays when I don't decide it myself ;-)

Comment: Any news ? For now I disabled the library but I can't  wait to have it back and working :-)  Do have an idea about what happened.?

Comment: @Sergeinsas, I am sorry. I saw your message and had no possibility to fix the bug. I did not change the code quite long time. Seems GAS developers changed something in the ScriptDB code. I have to find a workaround. I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: That's what I thought... as I said:  they shouldn't change things without telling!  Good luck for the fix

Comment: @Sergeinsas, fixed. Please update the library to the version 8. Seems a problem in ScriptDB.removeByIdBatch(..., true), i.e atomic deleting. I will create a sample and submit a bug. Thank you for patience.

Comment: @Sergeinsas. A [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2016) is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [more general issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502) about logger that was reported in july (since it used to work before that...) and I do hope Google will fix it since it's far more convenient than any other method to debug a script. You could vote for it too ;-)

In the meantime, Srik's suggestion is the only way I'm afraid...

EDIT : and, of course the utility library mentionned in the above post by Megabyte1024 which ils very helpfull and handy.