# File modified via append: changes dont show up in google drive folder on my pc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Using the following script to create/append lines to a file. Works fine within The Google-Online-Environment, I can look at the file and see how lines are appended. However, looking at the file via my Google Drive-Folder on my pc gives me only the first line (That one written during creation). The others only show up (Waited 2 hours) after closing and starting again google drive on my pc. So what can I do inside my script to do kind of "flush" to see the changes on my pc?

```
function appendFile (textArea) { // run by timer
  var d=new Date();
  var id;
  if ((id=ScriptProperties.getProperty ("fileId"))==null) {
    var f=DocsList.createFile("List", "Started at "+d+"\n");
    ScriptProperties.setProperty ("fileId", f.getId());
  }
  else {
    var f=DocsList.getFileById(id);
    f.append("Appended "+d+"\n");
    if (textArea!=undefined) {
      textArea.setText ("id="+id+"\n"+"name="+f.getName()+"\n"+"date="+d+"\nContents="+f.getContentAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you see the changes online, the script, in all likeliness works fine. YOu should check if the Google Drive application on your PC does the syncing. Is it running ? Can you see it in the taskbar ? Is it blocked by a firewall? Is it setup to work with your account ? Is the folder excluded in the list for syncing >

Comment: Google drive on my pc works fine. Also the file which is created by that script shows up very fast, but the contents dont change. I think the append-function does not trigger internally some change-flags which would lead to an update in google-drive on the pc.

Comment: Interesting... I'm trying your script, and I notice that the online document does not show the edits from the `append()` in real-time. I need to reload the file. This supports your theory that some trigger is missing from `append()`.

Comment: The documentation for the `append()` method says: "This method is only available for Google Apps accounts." I'm not using a Google Apps account, but I can use `append()`... maybe it just doesn't work right in a 'normal' google account? Could that be your problem, pbhd?

Comment: No, I have a google apps account. But, however, I gave up on using append, because its really slow. I got less then 10 appends per second, so for my purpose spreadsheets are a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, but in the opposite direction. (I am updating a file on my PC, copying it to Drive, and expecting it to sync to the cloud so apps-script can work on it.) I found that I had to delete and re-create the file to get it to sync. The same approach seems to work here.

I've commented out the Ui portions of your code, substituted logging to observe the operations, and modified it to ***trash then recreate the text file every time it's updated***. Ugly, but effective - the file on the PC's GDrive is updated immediately.

```
function appendFile (/*textArea*/) { // run by timer
  var d=new Date();
  var id;
  if ((id=ScriptProperties.getProperty ("fileId"))==null) {
    var f=DocsList.createFile("List", "Started at "+d+"\n");
    ScriptProperties.setProperty ("fileId", f.getId());
  }
  else {
    var f=DocsList.getFileById(id);
    var text = String.concat(f.getContentAsString(),
               "Appended "+d+"\n");
    f.setTrashed(true);
    f=DocsList.createFile("List",text);
    ScriptProperties.setProperty ("fileId", f.getId());
//    if (textArea!=undefined) {
//      textArea.setText ("id="+id+"\n"+"name="+f.getName()+"\n"+"date="+d+"\nContents="+f.getContentAsString());
//    }
    Logger.log("id="+id+"\n"+"name="+f.getName()+"\n"+"date="+d+"\nContents="+f.getContentAsString());
  }
}
```

Remaining problems:

- Remembering the id of the file is a waste of time, since it gets changed on every run.
- You can't rely on monitoring the text file, for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, something similar I tried too, and the file-contents during creation are immediately synced to the pc. But rewriting a file each time something changes? Wanted to use this for logging purposes, and that's just not practicable when used for large files.

Comment: I agree, I just don't see this working long-term for the purpose of logging. Why not use Logger? Despite documentation that it "does not work when executed from UiApp events nor when a script is published as a service", that capability has been [fixed recently](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502). Consider also megabyte1024's [Log Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599900/how-to-log-apps-script-with-user-interaction), although that won't sync to a PC in a way you can read off-line.